# Flutter camera plugin: how do I lockCaptureOrientation on either landscapeRight or landscapeLeft?

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, screen-orientation

I am writing a landscape flutter application that uses the camera plugin.

To make my app landscape, I have the following lines in my main:

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight, DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);
```

This does not prevent from receiving a landscape image from the camera stream so, after initializing the camera controller, I have the line

```
_controller?.lockCaptureOrientation(DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight);
```

With this line, the camera gives only landscape images, but now the app will not work properly in landscapeLeft. Is there a way to enforce the capture orientation to be either landscapeRight
or landscapeLeft?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify lockCaptureOrientation() after inialization and restart the camera screen.

```
  await cameraController?.initialize();
  await cameraController?.lockCaptureOrientation();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).